# Show one sidebar else don't show any sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I want only one sidebar onpage otherwise dont show any sidebar leave blank

```
**<?php get_sidebar("wp-forecast") ?>**
```

Comment: use if condition with side bar code

Comment: can you give me the code i have tried to find didn't get yet.

Comment: what is your condition to show and hide sidebar?

Comment: i just want to show one side bar and other all to hide. means just show one sidebar

Comment: do you have multiple sidebar on page?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a flag variable and set it to false:

```
 $displayed_sidebar = false
```

Then wrap the content of the function `get_sidebar` in a condition that checks if `displayed_sidebar` is false or not:

```
 if (!$displayed_sidebar) {

     $displayed_sidebar = true; // this prevents more than one sidebar to be displayed

     // ... the rest of the code here ...   

 }
```